# Event handlers and loops

Tags: java, loops, animation, event-handling, listener

I have a full screen window that plays a simple animation, and I want to make it so that when I press any key, the full screen is restored and the program stops.
The key listener class looks like this:

import java.awt.event.*;

public class key implements KeyListener {

```
private framerun animation=new framerun();

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){}
public void  keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
    animation.x=false;
}
```

}

The animation runs in a method, run, with a while loop which looks like this:

```
public void run(DisplayMode dm){

        Screen s=new Screen();
        s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
        while(true){
            try{
                System.out.println(x);
                Thread.sleep(300);

            }catch(Exception e){}
            if(!x)
                s.RestoreScreen();
            repaint();
        }
    }
```

PS: x is a boolean with initial value true, initiated in the constructor.

This is the main method:

```
public static void main(String args []){
        DisplayMode dm=new DisplayMode(800, 600,    16,DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);

        framerun f=new framerun();
        key k=new key();
        f.addKeyListener(k);
        f.run(dm); 
    }
```

Now this works perfectly if there is no while loop. The full screen closes and the program stop. But with the while loop there is no response when I press a key. The value of x doesn't change to false as expected.
Ideas?

Comment: Why can't you call `s.RestoreScreen` from the `MouseListener`?

Comment: I tried it, but it's as if it doesn't even notice the action when I press a key. It doesn't even change the value of x to false. That's the problem. Does the while loop clash with event listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get the `DisplayMode` switching to work, but it shouldn't make a difference.

Basically, `KeyListener` is fiddly.  It requires the component that it is attached to is focusable and has focus.

The following example basically uses a combination of `requestFocusInWindow` and `setFocusable` on a `JPanel` to try and force focus to the `JPanel`, so that when a key is typed, the `JPanel` can respond to it...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private DisplayMode defaultMode;

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
                defaultMode = gd.getDisplayMode();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

//              DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, DisplayMode.BIT_DEPTH_MULTI);
//              gd.setDisplayMode(dm);
                gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setFocusable(true);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Test"));
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });

            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    try {
                        GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
//                      gd.setDisplayMode(defaultMode);
                        gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
                    } catch (Throwable exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(TestPane.this).dispose();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Personlly, I'd recommend using the key bindings API, [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), but this focuses on binding a single key to a given action, but overcomes the focus issues related to `KeyListener`

Comment: I feel it's simpler than this. Are while loops and event listeners normally incompatible?

Comment: Depends on where the loops are running.  Swing is a single threaded environment, meaning that if you run a loop within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, the UI will stop responding as the EDT can no longer process the Event Queue

Comment: Could you recommend something that would satisfy my goals, which wouldn't be mindbogglingly difficult for a beginner like me? Something that would allow my animation to play but still give me the power to stop it using a key press.

Comment: I don't know, what's you goal?

Comment: Play the animation in full screen, but when I press a key on my keyboard the program stops and the screen returns to normal size.

Comment: You could use a Swing `javax.swing.Timer` to act as the main animation loop.  You could use a separate `Thread` to run the animation loop, but Swing it not thread safe, so you will need to ensure that any updates to the UI are done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details